# sessionstorage in angular project

Tags: javascript, local-storage, session-storage

in my angular 9 project the user, who does not opt for "remember me", i stored his login token and details on sessionStorage. and details of the user who selects to be remembered is stored on localstorage.

the problem arised when i noticed, that the user whose details are stored in sesssionstorage, cannot open a duplicate tab of the application, without loosing the token details. because the sessionstorage does not persist data from one tab to another.

how to go though this problem, storing data for either of users.. remembered/not remembered. so that the user can open other tabs too.

Comment: you can just save it in localStorage? or you can save it in your token

Answer (score 2):

That is actually the intended and default behavior of `sessionStorage`. A new tab is considered a second "session", and hence, will not have access to anything stored in a different session/tab.

From the docs:

- A page session lasts as long as the browser is open, and survives over page reloads and restores.
- Opening a page in a new tab or window creates a new session with the value of the top-level browsing context, which differs from how session cookies work.
- Opening multiple tabs/windows with the same URL creates sessionStorage for each tab/window.
- Closing a tab/window ends the session and clears objects in sessionStorage.

Therefore, `sessionStorage` is not what you want here. You're better off going with `localStorage` and using `removeItem()`.

Comment: so what proper logic i should follow for users who selects "not remeber me", i built the app likeif a user selects not to be remembered, the next time he reopens the app, he should be logged out..

Comment: As I mentioned above, use `localStorage` and `removeItem` for the ID of that user when they close the app. Then the next time they open the app their info will no longer be in their `localStorage`.

Comment: is there any such hook in angular which runs only on browser tab close. i got some but they execute even on page refresh.

Comment: There's no Angular hook for that specifically, no. Check out this implementation: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-browser-or-tab-close-event